# Dynamic variable into a dynamic type

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, dynamic-type-feature

Is it possible to generate a dynamic type and in a method a dynamic variable using reflection emit? The dynamic type would be something like the code below but created by using reflection emit.

```
public class MyDynamicType
{
    public void MyTests()
    {
        dynamic MyDynamicVar = 10;
        MyDynamicVar = "whatever";
    }
}
```

Comment: `dynamic` is part `object`, part compiler magic. Emit it as `object` and you should be fine. The compiler magic, if you need it, is something you will have to mimick if you want to act as the compiler. This part, you will **not** be fine, because mimicking the compiler is going to be super complex regarding dynamic types.

Comment: What is it your actually trying to achieve? There may be a better solution that generating a class on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this - but it would be *incredibly* difficult (at least if you want to do anything usefully dynamic - just assigning a value to a local varaible would be easy enough, but I assume your real code would do more than that). Dynamic typing is handled by the C# compiler; there's no IL for it... whereas Reflection.Emit is all about generating IL.

So this piece of code:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    dynamic x = "foo";
    dynamic y = x.Substring(1, 2);
}
```

generates the following IL - as well as a generated class, referred to in the IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       109 (0x6d)
  .maxstack  9
  .locals init (object V_0,
           object V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "foo"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>> Program/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
  IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0010
  IL_000e:  br.s       IL_0054
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0011:  ldstr      "Substring"
  IL_0016:  ldnull
  IL_0017:  ldtoken    Program
  IL_001c:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0022:  newarr     [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo
  IL_0027:  dup
  IL_0028:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0029:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_002a:  ldnull
  IL_002b:  call       class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags,
                                                                                                                                                                             string)
  IL_0030:  stelem.ref
  IL_0031:  dup
  IL_0032:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0033:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0034:  ldnull
  IL_0035:  call       class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags,
                                                                                                                                                                             string)
  IL_003a:  stelem.ref
  IL_003b:  dup
  IL_003c:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_003d:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_003e:  ldnull
  IL_003f:  call       class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags,
                                                                                                                                                                             string)
  IL_0044:  stelem.ref
  IL_0045:  call       class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder::InvokeMember(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags,
                                                                                                                                                               string,
                                                                                                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [mscorlib]System.Type>,
                                                                                                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.Type,
                                                                                                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo>)
  IL_004a:  call       class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<!0> class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>>::Create(class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)
  IL_004f:  stsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>> Program/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
  IL_0054:  ldsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>> Program/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
  IL_0059:  ldfld      !0 class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>>::Target
  IL_005e:  ldsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>> Program/'<>o__0'::'<>p__0'
  IL_0063:  ldloc.0
  IL_0064:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0065:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0066:  callvirt   instance !4 class [mscorlib]System.Func`5<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,int32,int32,object>::Invoke(!0,
                                                                                                                                                                !1,
                                                                                                                                                                !2,
                                                                                                                                                                !3)
  IL_006b:  stloc.1
  IL_006c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

You'd have to write Reflection.Emit code to generate all that IL yourself. I really, really don't think you want to do that.